# Trying to compare multiple sets of data from two data sets. Python

Tags: python, list, csv

I am trying to compare multiple sets of data from two different datasets. I have reference each csv using the csv.DictReader. I then made a function handler to handle each function. Each function handles a different set of data and the two datasets being used are being broken up into a group of functions.

So below is the function causing the error and there is no keyerror as there is no problem with the column name it is referencing. Each function is then handled by the secMastHandler() function and I reference each function as 
inputData = secMastHandler(). I can reference the data from each function as a list inputData[n] and it works fine to zip(inputData[a],inputData[b]) and do a conditional (if line[0] == line[1]:).

But more than two elements in the zip() and subsequent if statement does not work and get the error message about the key error. It just seems like such an odd error to get in this instance. So the real question is how can I compare these multiple datasets in the same if statement?

```
def frfSecDict(): ## function handling the frfpost data 
                  ## from the section file data set
    import csv
    reader = csv.DictReader(outData)
    for row in reader:
        frfpost = str(row['FRFPOST']) ## Line 61. There is not keyError here
        frfpostFlt = round(float(frfpost),3)
        yield frfpostFlt

line 61, in frfSecDict
    frfpost = str(row['FRFPOST'])
KeyError: 'FRFPOST'


def secMastHandler(): ## handler function for functions handling data from
                  ## multiple data sources
    gen0 = corrSecDict()
    gen1 = svySecDict() ## this is inputData[1]
    gen2 = frfSecDict() ## this is inputData[2]
    gen3 = trfSecDict()
    gen4 = corrMastDict()
    gen5 = svyMastDict() ## this is inputData[5]
    gen6 = frfMastDict() ## this is inputData[6]
    gen7 = trfMastDict()
    return gen0,gen1,gen2,gen3,\
        gen4,gen5,gen6,gen7

def SecMastPrinter(): ## this function should yield output from multiple
                  ## datasets based upon the conditions from
                  ## the zipped inputData datasets.
    inputData = secMastHandler()
    for line in zip(inputData[1],inputData[5],\
                inputData[2],inputData[6]): ## doesnt seem to like this
                                            ## second line in the zip
        if line[0] == line[1] and line[2] == line[3]: ## this not possible?
            output = line[:]
            yield output

def frfSecMastPrinter():
    inputData = secMastHandler()
    for line in zip(inputData[2],inputData[6]): ## but just a one line
                                                ## zip works just fine
        if line[0] == line[1]:
            output = line[:]
            yield output
```

Comment: Luckily your code is quite short, so I'd recommend starting from scratch and write unit tests first. This way you can build while you're checking continuously. This is the same approach I'd take to help you out, but in this case you should easily be able to solve it by yourself. Btw. try to improve your code style (naming and formatting), that helps a lot ;-)

Comment: Yes this section of the code is the only part where I have trying to do this particular functionality. It isn't a long big of code. I apologize for the esoteric nature of my code. I am the only one who really sees my code since I just use them for analyzing data. So I tend to just design them for myself.

Comment: So can I just not zip that many elements at once?

Comment: As you see, there are not that many answers yet. This is mostly because your problem is not understandable and reproducible within– let's say –5 minutes ;-) Simply provide an example data set, your desired output and include the PART of your code, which tries to solve that particular problem. Dead simple. You'll immediately get help if you do these little prerequisites. And btw., the amount of data for `zip` should not be the problem. I'd highly recommend providing a ready-to-run piece of code which everyone can check out. Your code is not copy&paste&run ready at all.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I knew this would be kind of difficult to post and I should have made it easier to work with. Basically what im trying to do is use Python to do what I already do in SQL. Well, the process starts in Excel then moves on to PL-SQL Developer. I just wanted to do the whole process in one compiling of a Python program. But for now I think ill step back and pick this up at another time and I wrote a perfectly good query that does what I need. Thanks!